# Web Service API Calls

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest

I have developed an API - getAllDates() and it is being called up by different components. I need to have slightly different functionality for one of the component calls. How can I differentiate between these calls when none of the consumers pass a USER_AGENT for calling my API? Is there any way out?

Any leads would be helpful! Thanks in advance!

Comment: 'slightly different functionality for one of the component call' Based on what?

Comment: It is based on the caller. I need to identify uniquely who the caller is. I need to understand if this is possible without a user_agent.

Comment: How do you want to identify the caller?

Comment: Since the consumer and producer both have been built up, we cannot add user_agent now. Now, I get identical calls from all components. I need suggestion for how to differentiate between these calls depending on the caller.

Comment: Maybe they come from different IPs?

Comment: Yes, they do come from different IPs. But would that be a right way to differentiate?

Comment: Probably it would not be enough. I see no way how to do what you want.